# Where did the rebel fleet go after Haven in Canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, the-rebel-alliance

At the end of Empire, the last thing we see is the heroes looking at a protostar from the rebel rendezvous, known as Haven.

I would like to know where they went after that. Did they go straight to a new base, were they space-bound for a while, or did they spend most of their time at Haven?

Answers in Disney's Canon, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After leaving Hoth, the Rebel Alliance rendezvoused at **Sullust.**

> ON THE EDGE OF THE GALAXY, many parsecs from any Imperial star system, **the rebel fleet has gathered near the planet Sullust.
>
>   They’ve given up on maintaining a base on land.** This is all that’s left, a handful of strange, patched-together starships, a few partial squadrons of fighters, and, of course, the Millennium Falcon.
>   All the pilots have assembled on the flagship to hear from Mon Mothma, the brave leader of the Rebel Alliance.
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Note that the Emperor was well aware of this but chose not to engage them, preferring for them to come into his ambush rather than scatter again.

> **VADER:** *What of the reports of the Rebel fleet massing near Sullust?*
>
> **EMPEROR:** *It is of no concern. Soon the Rebellion will be crushed and young  Skywalker will be one of us! Your work here is finished, my
>   friend. Go  out to the command ship and await my orders.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)</sup></sub>